# Storing EXIF GPS data as decimal degrees

Tags: python, jpeg, exif

I was wondering if there's any way to store GPSLatitude and GPSLongitude as decimal degrees rather than the default way of degrees, minutes, and seconds (DMS). I know how to convert between the two, but for this specific project I'm asked if it's possible to actually encode the GPS data into the JPEG EXIF data as decimal degrees.
Any ideas?

Comment: The way they're stored in EXIF is defined in a standard (3 rational values each for lat/long). If you change the data format, then other applications won't be able to read the data. You can create a private tag with your format.

Comment: @BitBank Is there any online tutorials for figuring out how to create a private tag? I haven't heard about this before.

Comment: Any private data you put in the JPEG markers or EXIF that's unrecognized will be ignored by other readers. Does your data need to be in the EXIF marker? It might be easier to just stick it in a private APPx marker (e.g. FFE5)